# SQLiteException querying rows with AS statment

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite db of locations. (each row in the db is a location with a lat and lng) I want to query that db to find the closest locations to me. I'm able to return just the locations when I do something like this, I get back a list of the distance numbers which is good.

```
SELECT  ( 38.9672071 - lat) * ( 38.9672071 - lat) + ( -77.5124503 - lng) * ( -77.5124503- lng) * 0.6045156141643896 AS distance FROM pois ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 2
```

But I don't want to just have the distance to each point, I want to select the whole row from my db ordered by the distance formula that is created inline. Here is my sqlite query:

```
SELECT * ( 38.9671889 - lat) * ( 38.9671889 - lat) + ( -77.5124857 - lng) * ( -77.5124857- lng) * 0.6045159247970772 AS distance FROM pois ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 2
```

Which gives me this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * ( 38.9671889 - lat) * ( 38.9671889 - lat) + ( -77.5124857 - lng) * ( -77.5124857- lng) * 0.6045159247970772 AS distance FROM pois ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 2
```

I'm a noob at sql statements and I'm not sure what the syntax error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a comma after `*`.

Try this:

```
SELECT *, ( 38.9671889 - lat) * ( 38.9671889 - lat) + ( -77.5124857 - lng) * ( -77.5124857- lng) * 0.6045159247970772 AS distance FROM pois ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: You are the wind beneath my wings! That did it. Fastest fix ever.